# Problems trying to log in with Google OAuth

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I have an Asp.Net MVC project where I set up a user login using Google login credentials.
In development environment everything went well, and I was able to log in with my Google user, but in production nothing is working.
I'm getting an error like: (Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch)
The URI shown in the details is different from the URI that is configured in the Google credentials panel.
No matter how many times I change the URI address, the address shown in the details is always the same (http://www.zzonalivre.com.br/signin-google).
I already checked that my client_id and client_secret. Everything is the same as the google console.
My site runs in a Doker container, I don't know if this is relevant. But anyway, any ideas on how to solve this?
[image]

[image]

My file with google credentials

[image]

My setup code in Startup.cs

[image]